# Is there a way to exclude resources from default tags in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am in the process of adding default tags to all our resources in terraform with the following:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      terraform_managed = "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Now it seems to be wanting to recreate some of my EC2 instances due to the user data being updated which is populated by a template file.

Is there a way to ignore data blocks from the default tags:

```
data "template_file" "ec2_user_data" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/user_data.tpl")

  vars = {
    region         = var.region
    vr._version    = var.vr_version
  }
}



~ user_data   = "110437fa31b8fe5795165cf9973be6c5b" -> (known after apply) # forces replacement
```

This is the only change to the code so nothing else could be causing this.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Since the tags are not being passed as input variables to the template file, the actual root cause here is more likely a non-constant intrinsic variable in the template for the user data. Please share the user data template. Also consider upgrading `data.template_file` to the `templatefile()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from data.template_file to the templatefile() fixed the issue.

Thanks @matt-schuchard

Answer (score 0):

Since Terraform data sources are defined outside and managed outside of Terraform, `default_tags` in the AWS Terraform provider will have no effect on  `data` sources.

The change shown in the plan is a change in the `user_data.tpl` file